# How to find out array content/ boolean

Tags: arrays, boolean

I want to help with finding content in array. I saved boolean answers(True,False)in array and I would like to find out that, if in array is for example more than 20x True. I would like to create condition on that fact:
`((if true in array>20): return True, else: return False`. That was only simple example for better understanding my problem)
Hope, it is clear.
Thank you for help

Comment: Please add a tag to your question noting the language / syntax you're using (MySQL, T-SQL, PHP, Java, VBA, C#, etc.).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this problem any language specific or you are asking for pseudo-programming syntax?

For example, in Python:

```
def check(arr, num):
    if sum(arr) > num: return True
    else: return False

>>> A = [True, False, False, True, True, False, False, True, False, True]
>>> check(A, 4)
      True
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$myTrueElements = array_filter($myArray, function($el){
    return $el === true;
});

return count($myTrueElements) > 20;
```

Comment: Could i use this function in Python somehow?